# Android: activities and back-function

Tags: android, android-activity, parent, back

I developed an app with six activities. I switch these activities with intents. In the Manifest.xml there are no parent activities listed. This is the structure:

(A) start

(B) make input

(C) evaluate input response/results

(D) more results/details

(E) more details

(F) more different details

---

(F) is an activity that can be started from (C) and (E) - could have two various parents (C) and (F).

(C) <--> (F) no problems on forward and back navigation.
Furthermore, there are no problems on (C) <--> (D).

But if I go (C) --> (D) --> (E) (no problem till this point) and then from (E)/(D) --> (C) is an error. And this error has a different manner on Android 2.2 and Android 4.x.

**On Android 2.2:**
(D) normally restarts (C) and destroys itself. (C) runs from restart->start->resume to pause and (E) will be started with onCreate().

**On Android 4.x:**
(E) calls itself as an new object/activity (onCreate) and destroys the old activity. This happened 3-5 times and then normally (E) restarts (D) and (D) restarts (C).

It's confusing and i can't find the problem. Any ideas?

Kind Regards

MacLeod

Comment: I din't completely understand ur question.. but I guess there is some thing to do with the launchmode of ur activity..
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Comment: Your question is confusing, also you have not mentioned the errors you get in each approach. Also note that NavUtils behaves differentyl pre JellyBean and post JellyBean.